# c++ undefined reference errors when trying to compile opengl project

Tags: opengl, g++, linker-errors, glew

I tried to compile my c++/opengl-project with the g++ command.
(I need this since I want to recompile it on every target system with a second self-written program.)

But when I execute:

```
g++ -Iinclude -Isrc $(pkg-config --cflags freetype2) -L/usr/X11R6/lib -L/usr/lib $(pkg-config --libs glew) -lglut $(pkg-config --libs glu) $(pkg-config --libs freetype2) main.cpp  (some more source files) src/Vec4.cpp
```

I get lots of 'undefined references' for gl/glu/glut/glew-functions, so I guess something fails with the libs:

```
/tmp/ccUm2dEl.o: In function `Box::render()':
Box.cpp:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `glEnable'
Box.cpp:(.text+0x72c): undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
Box.cpp:(.text+0x736): undefined reference to `glBegin'
...
TextureManager.cpp:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
TextureManager.cpp:(.text+0x295): undefined reference to `glTexImage2D'
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
```

I did some research, but according to what I found out the above command should be correct.
I checked the pkg-config-calls as well and they seem to work. 
Before I tried the g++ command I used the Codeblocks IDE to compile it and it worked. Here are my settings:

**In** Compiler settings|Other options:

```
`pkg-config --cflags freetype2`
```

**In** Linker settings|Link libraries:

```
glut
```

**In** Linker settings|Other linker options:

```
`pkg-config --libs glu`
`pkg-config --libs glew`
`pkg-config --libs freetype2`
```

**In** Search directories|Compiler:

```
include
src
```

My system (Ubuntu Precise):

```
$ uname -a
Linux andromeda 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ -dumpversion
4.6

glxinfo
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.43

Codeblocks-version: 10.04
```

Thanks in advice

Comment: Put your files (.cpp and .o) _before_ the libraries you link to on the command line.

Comment: I don't see libGL being added. Try adding `-lGL` after the X11 libraries.

Comment: By the way, libGL is added with `pkg-config --libs glu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you link in the wrong order. The GNU linker wants its libraries in kind of reverse order, so if you place the linker libraries *last* on the command line it should go better.

Comment: +1 If object or library A requires B, then A needs to before B in the command line. This holds for `.o` files and libs linked with `-l`.

Comment: _library A requires B_ I already paid attention to that, but thanks.
I put the libs to the end and it worked! Thanks, you saved my day.
I never got an answer that fast on any other forum before, seems like stackoverflow is much more useful than I thought.